# How to configure Istio Virtual Service destination protocol

Tags: kubernetes, istio

How can I configure Istio VirtualService to route traffic to a destination backend that listens on HTTPS?

configuring `protocol: HTTPS` or `scheme: HTTPS` didn't work.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-rpi-access
spec:
  hosts:
  - "test.example.com"
  gateways:
  - api-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        port: https
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: some-https-service
        port:
          number: 8443
          protocol: HTTPS
        # scheme: HTTPS
```

Here is my gateway:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "test.example.com"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got a destination rule setup also, as an example:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: dr-test.example.com
spec:
  host: test.example.com
  trafficPolicy: # Apply to all ports
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 443
      loadBalancer:
        simple: LEAST_CONN
```

[some good information on istio routing](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)

Comment: the destination rule did the trick, I'll share it here, thank you

Answer (score 6):

In order to perform the TLS termination on istio-ingressgateway and send https traffic to the backend, I had to add the following `DestinationRule`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: some-https-service
spec:
  host: diary
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
```

here are the yamls for `Gateway` and `VirtualService`:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: api-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
      privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
    hosts:
    - "test.example.com"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: ext-access
spec:
  hosts:
  - "test.example.com"
  gateways:
  - api-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        port: https
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: some-https-service
        port:
          number: 8443
```

Comment: faq man, you saved my life! I tried `tls` route with `VirtualService`, it keeps returning me 404 which I dont really understand. But `DestinationRule` did the trick! Is there any reason that `DestinationRule` combines `http` route would do the trick?

Answer (score 3):

Currently Your gateway is configured to Terminate TLS on gateway. Your VirtualService also needs little modifications.

You need to change Your TLS mode of Your gateway to Passthrough.

```
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

According to [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/#configure-an-ingress-gateway) documentation:

> 1. Define a `Gateway` with a `server` section for port 443. Note the `PASSTHROUGH` TLS mode which instructs the gateway to pass the ingress traffic AS IS, without terminating TLS.
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: Gateway
> metadata:
>   name: mygateway
> spec:
>   selector:
>     istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
>   servers:
>   - port:
>       number: 443
>       name: https
>       protocol: HTTPS
>     tls:
>       mode: PASSTHROUGH
>     hosts:
>     - nginx.example.com
> ```
>
> 2. Configure routes for traffic entering via the `Gateway`:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: VirtualService
> metadata:
>   name: nginx
> spec:
>   hosts:
>   - nginx.example.com
>   gateways:
>   - mygateway
>   tls:
>   - match:
>     - port: 443
>       sniHosts:
>       - nginx.example.com
>     route:
>     - destination:
>         host: my-nginx
>         port:
>           number: 443
> ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do want the istio ingressgateway to preform the TLS termination in order to get visibility on the traffic and to get the certificate from istio ingressgateway.